# Unable to replace string based on not criteria in pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column in a pandas dataframe in which i want to replace all values that aren't 'US' into 'Other'. I tried the below code.

```
dat.country.str.replace(to_replace='^(?!.*US)', value='Other', regex=True)
```

However, instead of getting 'Other', i am getting a concatenated results of 'Other' and old value. For example, if old value was 'China', above code gives me result 'OtherChina'

Can anyone help?

Comment: The regex will be `to_replace='^(?!US$).*$'` and do not forget to assing the new value to the column.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, please post this as an answer. It worked for me. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using lookaheads combined with replacements, remember that the lookaheads themselves are [zero-width assertions](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#zero_width) - they don't actually *match* (consume) any characters - so, combine them with a `.+` (`.*` if you want to replace empty values):

```
^(?!US$).+ //disallow whole string match
^(?!.*US).+ //disallow partial matches
```